# Do I have to add my workspace to the ros environment every time I start the terminal?

Tags: ros, package, create

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have started working on the tutorial and in the third tutorial (Creating ros package) I was instructed to add my workspace the ros environment. Suppose I have created the package and added my workspace to the ros environment  then I closed the terminal and the system, so the next time I open the terminal and my workspace using ($ cd ~/my_workspace), do I have to add my workspace to the ros environment again.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228059/do-i-have-to-add-my-workspace-to-the-ros-environment-every-time-i-start-the-terminal-?/) by [ATOM](https://answers.ros.org/users/26144/atom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are working under Ubuntu, to avoid having to add your workspace manually to the ros environment you should add the following line to the file *~/.bashrc*

```
source ~/my_workspace/devel/setup.bash
```

This will automatically load your workspace every time you open a new terminal.

Hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2016-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DBServ](https://answers.ros.org/users/33529/dbserv/) on 2018-02-05**:
I had the same problem like ATOM, so I also added you given line to my system-wide bash.bashrc-file.
But it says, that I don't have permission to save it. What can I do? Thanks in advance!

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2018-02-19**:
To modify the system-wide bashrc file you need root privileges. Try using sudo.